# CSS to zoom in background image and scroll up text from bottom to up

Tags: html, css

My objective is to have a CSS which when user hovers the DIV it will

1. zoom (scale up) the background image
2. move the text within the div from bottom to the top (but want to keep the text size unchanged)

My initial code is like the following

```css
.wrapper {
    padding: 50px 50px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
    bottom:0;
}

.parent {
    width: 45%;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.child {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;

}

/* Several different images */
.bg-one {background-image: url(https://media.timeout.com/images/101602611/image.jpg);}


a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-decoration:none;  
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.parent:hover .child, .parent:focus .child {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -o-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

.parent:hover .child:before, .parent:focus .child:before {
    display: block;
}

.parent:hover a, .parent:focus a {
    display: block;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    transition: 0.5s;
    top:-100px;
}

.parent a {
    display: block;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color:white;
    top:100px;
}


.child:before {
    content: "";
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child bg-one" onclick="javascript:alert('test');">
      <a href="#">
         Los Angeles
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Now it has 2 problems

1. actually I just use top:100px; and change to top:-100px; , which actually is not vertically-bottom aligned moving to vertical-top aligned. This is not an ideal solution I think because if the text is too long it may overflow
2. when user hovers the DIV, the bottom image can be zoomed (scaled up), but I want the text to remain the same size (now the text also scaled up)

I will be very grateful if someone can tell me how to fix the above two issues. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by putting the anchor tag outside the child div. Like this:

```css
.wrapper {
        padding: 50px 50px;
        max-width: 1200px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 80px;
        bottom: 0;
      }

      .parent {
        width: 45%;
        margin: 20px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .child {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s;
        transition: all 0.5s;
      }

      /* Several different images */
      .bg-one {
        background-image: url(https://media.timeout.com/images/101602611/image.jpg);
      }

      a {
        font-size: 35px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: calc(100% - 50px);
        right: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 50px;
        transition: top 0.5s ease 0s;
        color: #fff;
      }

      .parent:hover .child,
      .parent:focus .child {
        -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
        -o-transform: scale(1.3);
        transform: scale(1.3);
      }

      .parent:hover .child:before,
      .parent:focus .child:before {
        display: block;
      }

      .parent:hover a,
      .parent:focus a {
        display: block;
        color: #ffffff;
        transform: scale(1);
        transition: 0.5s;
        top: 0px;
      }

      .child:before {
        content: "";
        display: none;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child bg-one" onclick="javascript:alert('test');"></div>
    <a href="#">Los Angeles</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift answer, it fixed the 2nd problem, but can you also tell me how to fix the 1st problem (change the text alignment from (initial) bottom aligned to (hover) move to top-aligned instead of moving top from 100px to -200px ) ?

Comment: I have updated the CSS code. Now it is aligned at bottom in start and then aligned to top when hovered.

Comment: Check and tell is this what you wanted or not? @KenLee

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the ways to achieve that effect.

```css
#zoomimg,#movetxt {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#zoomimg {
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_%28JPEG-HDR%29.jpg");
}

#zoomimg:hover {
    -webkit-animation: zooming 5s infinite;
    animation: zooming 5s infinite;
}

#zoomimg:hover #movetxt {
    -webkit-animation: moving 5s infinite;
    animation: moving 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes zooming {
    from {
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    to {
      background-size: 150% 150%;
    }
}

@keyframes moving {
    from {
      transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    to {
      transform: translateY(-200px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="zoomimg">
  <div id="movetxt">
    Line one<br/>
    Line two
  </div>
</div>
```